# Stream response from custom RASA actions to the chatbot

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, gpt, chatbot, software-development

I am using RASA PRO with CALM.
I was thinking of using openai api within a custom action and stream the streaming response coming from openai to my chatbot. Openai is giving me streaming response and i am doing “dispatcher.utter_message(openai_res_chunk)” from actions, but the response is not getting streamed in chunks to my bot and is available only after last chunk from openai. I am also passing “stream”: True while sending request to rasa server, but nothing is working. How to achieve this?